Why does varargs get more preference than Object for null value?
Here are two code snippets for example
class HelloWorld {
    public void method(Object a){
        System.out.println("object");
    }
    
    public void method(int... a){
        System.out.println("varargs");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
        h.method(10);
    }
}

Output - object
class HelloWorld {
    public void method(Object a){
        System.out.println("object");
    }
    
    public void method(int... a){
        System.out.println("varargs");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
        h.method(null);
    }
}

Output - varargs
For the first code, the method with Object argument is called because it can handle the int value and has more preference than varargs.However, when i call the method with a null value, even though object can handle a null value and has more preference than varargs, the varargs method is called.
Why is that?
This is showing up as a duplicate question but in that question the methods are - void method(int a) and void method(int... a). In this case varargs is called because int is a base type which cannot be null. But in my question the method takes an objects which can be null. So why does it not handle it.

BTW same behavior with method(int[] a) instead of method(int... a) (since int[] is more specific than Object)

"... object can handle a null value and has more preference than varargs": no it doesn't. Anything gets more preference than Object, by the 'most-specific' rule.

@user207421 then why when i pass a number, object method is called? int... is more specific than object.

@Karan because when you call method(1) it's syntactic sugar for method(new int[] { 1 }) and in that sense, a single object is considered a better fit than constructing an array behind the scenes. The JLS says that in the first 2 stages, varargs are ignored when determining overload resolution. More detail in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541615/13963086
